# Incorrect output for finding second largest number in a list

Tags: python

I wrote this program to find the largest and second largest among a list received from input in one line, with whitespace in between elements.But without using buit-in functions such as max or sorted. This works properly when all the numbers are positive, but when the input includes negative numbers, it prints the wrong output. What is wrong with this code?

```py
def second_largest_value(number_list):
    max_num = number_list[0]
    max2_num = number_list[0]
    for num in number_list:
        if max_num < num:
            max_num = num

    for num1 in number_list:
        if num1 != max_num & num1 > max2_num:
            max2_num = num1
    return print(f"largest number is: {max_num} \n \n and the second largest is: {max2_num}")


ls = list(map(int,input().split()))
second_largest_value(ls)
```

Comment: `&` doesn't mean what you think it does in python (hint: it's not a logical operator).

Comment: It doesn't work with positive numbers either – try `[2,1]`and `[1,2,3]`

Comment: Please note that returning the result of `print` just has your function returning `None`. You can remove the `return`.

Comment: Also, though it is not essential in this case, you should demonstrate expected and actual output in a question like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inappropriate use of ampersand (bitwise *and*) is the core issue as has already been pointed out. However, there are other potential issues with the code in question. What if the user only inputs one number or maybe even none?

So let's consider a more robust approach.

```
# return highest value and second highest value as a tuple
def get_values(user_input):  # user_input is a string
    try:
        if (data := sorted(map(int, user_input.split()))): # ensure that the list isn't empty
            if len(data) == 1:
                return data[0], None
            return data[-1], data[-2]
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return None, None

user_input = input('Please enter some numbers separated by whitespace: ')

hi, lo = get_values(user_input)

print(f'High={hi}, 2nd highest={lo}')
```

Here we get the function to do all the work. Splitting and mapping in the main program is not the best approach IMO. Rather just pass the input string as entered to the function. That's where we split it and convert it to a list of integers (sorted). Also allow for the potential input of values that cannot be converted to integer and furthermore check that there are an appropriate number of items in the list.

Answer (score 4):

`&` is a bitwise operator -- it is *not* how you express the boolean form of AND.

You should use the `and` keyword instead:

```py
if num1 != max_num & num1 > max2_num:
```

should be

```py
if num1 != max_num and num1 > max2_num:
```

---

**Explanation:**

A commenter pointed out that `&` does work with booleans. This explanation will demonstrate why it doesn't work in this case.

Using [this table](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) for operator precedence:

```py
if num1 != max_num & num1 > max2_num:
```

is equivalent to

```py
if num1 != (max_num & num1) > max2_num:
```

Python performs the three checks in the following order:

1. It finds the value of `max_num & num1` (i.e. it performs a bitwise operation between these two numbers).
2. The result of the operation is checked for inequality against `num1`.
3. The result of the operation from the first step is checked against the value of `max2_num`.

This use of bitwise operators is clearly not what we're looking for, so we use `and` instead:

```py
if num1 != max_num and num1 > max2_num:
```

`and` has a lower precedence that the comparison operators, so those comparisons will occur first, and then we check whether both comparisons evaluated to `True` using `and`.

Comment: So, shouldn't this question be closed as a typo?

Comment: I don't think so on this one. If OP had mistyped "and" in their code and then asked why their code had a `SyntaxError`, that would be worth closing as a typo. OP clearly thought that the bitwise-AND and boolean-AND were the same -- **this issue was not motivated by a typo**, even though the fix may be simple.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark Thanks for letting me know more about closed by typo.

Comment: @Dennis -- I've added an explanation for why it is a bitwise operator in this case. Let me know if anything's still unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just sort the list.

```py
def second_largest_value(number_list):
    order = sorted(number_list)
    largest = order[-1]
    second_largest = order[-2]
    print(f"largest number is: {largest}")
    print(f" and the second largest is: {second_largest}.")
```

A different version that is more similar to your code would be this:

```py
def second_largest_value(number_list):
    big = max(number_list)
    second = max(x for x in number_list if x != big)
    print(f"largest number is: {big}")
    print(f" and the second largest is: {second}.")
```

Answer (score 1):

It would work with `&`, even though it's not a logical operator but a bitwise operator, if it weren't for the fact that it has the highest precedence in the expression.

```
num1 != max_num & num1 > max2_num
```

is equivalent to

```
num1 != (max_num & num1) > max2_num
```

which, through funky Python shorthand, is equivalent to

```
num1 != (max_num & num1) and (max_num & num1) > max2_num
```

This only produces your expected results by accident, for very few inputs.

For instance, it fails with `[2,1]` ("largest number is: 2 and the second largest is: 2") and `[1,2,3]` ("largest number is: 3 and the second largest is: 1").

Through genuinely bad luck, all the positive lists you tested with produced what you expected.

The logical operator you're looking for is `and`.

Answer (score -1):

```
def second_largest_value(number_list):
     number_list.sort(reverse=True)
     max_ele=max(number_list) 
     for i in number_list:
        if i<max_ele:
            return i
     return max_ele
ls = list(map(int,input().split()))
print(second_largest_value(ls))
```

find max of list , compare it with list element :list sorted in descending order ,
return that element which is just smaller then max element
if all element are equal return any(max element)

Comment: If `number_list` is sorted, there's no need to use `max` on it. The biggest element will be the first, and the next biggest will be the second.